# backup of app database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipod-touch

i need to place a backup database in my iphone. so i want any place outside my app folder where i can place the backup database so that if due to any problem my app crashes the user has a copy of his data.

any other idea except of placing data on a remote server is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does it need to be outside your app folder, you could just copy and rename your database file and keep it in your app folder. I'm not sure it's possible to write outside your app folder.

Comment: because if my app crashes due to any reason. or the user delete it by-chance then at least he has his data saved.

Comment: i know this is something that apple will not allow me. but even then i want to find a way to that

Comment: It's pretty difficult to delete by mistake, and to be honest it's not your problem. Your only option is a remote server. Don't waste your time looking for other solutions. Of course if you jailbreak I'm sure you can.

Comment: Yeah, you're effectively trying to forcibly keep data around on your user's phones even if they DELETE your app -- that'd piss ME off, for one. ;)